# something like a using declaration for enums?

Tags: c++, enums, using

Basically this is what I'd like to do:

```
struct A {
    enum E {
        X, Y, Z
    };
};

template <class T>
struct B {
    using T::E;
};

// basically "import" the A::E enum into B.
std::cout << B<A>::X << std::endl;
```

The reason why is that I want to basically inject the implementation details into my template class. At the same time, the enum of the "model" reflects information that I want the user to be able to have for a particular instantiation of a template. Is this possible?

I know that I could have `B` inherit from `A`, but I think that isn't an ideal solution because I want to be able to add new "models" without changing the guts of `B`.

**EDIT:** Now that I've though about it, inheritance doesn't necessarily need to be ruled out. Perhaps the following is ideal:

```
struct A {
    enum E {
        X, Y, Z
    };
};

template <class T>
struct B : A {
};

int main() {
    std::cout << B<A>::X << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
struct A {
    enum E {
        X, Y, Z
    };
};

template <class T>
struct B {
    typedef typename T::E E;
};

// basically "import" the A::E enum into B.
int main(void)
{
    std::cout << B<A>::E::X << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
0
```

I do get a warning about non-standard extension in that qualified name so perhaps there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Anyway to get rid of that intermediate `::E` in that `cout` statement?

Comment: And it doesn't seem to work with gcc 4.5.1: `error: 'B<A>::E' is not a class or namespace`

Comment: @Evan - :-) will let you know, I imagine so... see edited version (last line). I am on Visual C++ v10

Comment: @Steve: i think you have the best non-inheritance solution, So I'm giving you the accept. But now that I think about it, inheritance with templates may be perfect for what I need. See my edit of my question.

Comment: @Steve: That won't compile under C++03, since an `enum` is not a true type.  You can change the `typedef` in `B` to: `typedef T E` and get the same usage, though.

Comment: @Evan - yes, that looks good.  @Travis - trying to test this, did you lose something in code formatting?  Please feel free to edit my answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do

```
template <class T>
struct B {
    typedef typename T::E E;
};
```

Comment: that creates an instance of the enum. I want to basically "import" the enum type itself into the scope of `B`

Comment: @Evan Teran: Got it after your comment. I made an edit to fit to your requirement.